# Watch execution path in chrome without putting breakpoints

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to see what functions get called, live, without putting any breakpoints in chrome dev tool ?

Answer (score 0):

You can put a `console.trace()` call in a function to see how it gets invoked further up. The call stack will be logged to the Console during the execution.

You could try using the Timeline to check this too, but there tends to be a lot of noise to get through. I created a small example where I have three functions that call each other.

[image: Timeline Call Tree]

Otherwise, you'd need to apply dynamic analysis techniques to capture execution context throughout your app through custom code transformations. For example, a simple technique for small scenarios would be to inject console statements into your functions and continue the original execution by using the [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) technique.

There are efforts being made in the community to improve developer tooling in this area.